# How to save client data to database after Stripe payment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I have a React application where the client fills out a form to be saved to my database. The client then proceeds to make a Stripe based payment. Only after receiving the payment confirmation should the data be uploaded.

The form data includes multiple attributes such as follows

```
data = {
   name: "Mike",
   summary: "some long text",
   ...
}
```

The workflow would similar to the following:

```
Client fills out form -> Payment -> Payment confirmation -> Post-payment action (uploading the data from step 1)
```

I am aware of Stripe's webhooks as well as the `line_items`, but I was wondering if using the latter would be best practice as some of the attribute values in `data` can be quite long. Is there a more common approach to this case?

Comment: if you want to update the database after the payment is succesfull from the backend directly you can follow this tutorial [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4E0WOUYF-QI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4E0WOUYF-QI), and this one shows more of the node integration [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YTc0Zi70AjM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YTc0Zi70AjM)

Comment: The first link you give only saves basic info like price. What if you want to store it like other properties as well? @c0dm1tu

Comment: can you say at what minute? from client to server or from server to database? you can pass any info you want

Comment: beside customer_email, succes_url, cancel_url, line_items ...etc, you can pass `metadata` object and place anything you want in there names, addresses, emails... (this is in the checkoutSession function in the backend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as some of the attribute values in data can be quite long.

What problem are you trying to solve? Prevent database overflow? Avoid sending large amounts of data in API requests? For both cases, it is suitable to create a temporary record in the database, which will be deleted when your webhook will catch the `checkout.session.expired` event (for example).

Answer (score 0):

Stripe [recommends](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/handling-payment-events) that you handle any post-payment actions/fulfilment using their events with a webhook. In this case you'd listen for the [`payment_intent.succeeded` event](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-payment_intent.succeeded) and create a webhook handler that saves the required fields/information fro the [Payment Intent object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object) to your database.